# Water splash for advertisment

Tags: physics, fluid-simulation, force-fields

I modeled a shower gel and I'am quite satisfied with the result. 
I now want to make water splash around it similar to this picture

[image: Example picture]

I tried to "fake" it with particle systems but that didn't work quite well. 
I also tried to let the water flow in from the left and right side so it would splash up when it hits the bottle, but that didn't work well either.

What I would like to do is put the bottle on a shallow resting water and then give the water around the bottle a twisted impulse upwards so it splashes similar to the picture I included. Maybe it could work with a force field or something like that but I couldn't figure out how.

I know the basics of fluid simulation as I followed Blender Guru's "photorealistic fruit splash" tutorial and did some other stuff like a wine splashing in a wine glass.

Comment: You need to sculpt the water if it is a still image. You have the best control and you will get the result the quickest. Simulation in Blender is not that powerful, it would take a long long loooong time to get exactly what you want.

Comment: How do I start when I sculpt it from scratch? Schould I create a low-poly mesh that is roughly the shape of the water/splash and then sculpt it in sculpt mode?

Comment: Yes, pretty much. Here is something similar: http://www.cgarena.com/freestuff/tutorials/zbrush/dream/dream6.html. From the general shape you sculpt the details. You get an exact control of the water composition around your object and you can match it with camera to get the best shape.

Comment: You could spray metaballs using a particle simulation set to fluid. Bake this out then sculpt from that?

Comment: Per 3pointedit's comment: [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PP14rVhgX9M) 13:24

Comment: Glen Alexandrov has a great tutorial for liquid splash : https://youtu.be/I0Tz1U6A5vI